# can a message sent to channel be lost?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

The question is in the title. Let's say I have several goroutines (more than 100) all of which eventually send data to one chan (name it `mychan := make(chan int)`) One another goroutine does `<- mychan` in an endless for loop Is it okay or the chan can happen to lose some data? Should I use buffered chan instead? Or perhaps I am to create a chan and a "demon" goroutine that will extract message for each worker goroutine?

Comment: Is your program exiting while there are active goroutines still processing data? That could make it appear that the messages you sent got lost.

Answer (score 2):

No, they can't be lost.

While the language spec does not in any way impose any particular implementation on channels, you can think of them as [semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) protecting either a single value (for the single message) or an array/list of them (for buffered channels).

The semantics are then enforced in such a way that as soon as a goroutine wants to send a message to a channel, it tries to acquire a free data slot using that semaphore, and then either succeeds at sending—there's a free slot for its message—or blocks—when there isn't.  As soon as such a slot appears—someone has received an existing message—the sending succeeds and the sending goroutine gets unblocked.

This is a simplified explanation. In other words, channels in Go is not like message queues which usually are happy with losing messages.

On a side note, I'm not really sure what happens if the receiver panics in some specific state when it's about to receive your message. In other words, I'm not sure whether Go guarantees that the message is either sent or not in the presence of a receiver panicking in an unfortunate moment.

Oh, and there's that grey area of the main goroutine exiting (that one running the `main.main()` function): the spec states clear than the main goroutine does not wait for any other goroutines to complete when it exits. So unless you somehow arrange for the synchronized controlled shutdown of all your spawned goroutines, I believe they may lose messages.  On the other hand, in this case the world is collapsing anyway…

Answer (score 2):

If something has been successfully sent into the channel then no, it can't be lost in correctly working environment (I mean if you're tampering with your memory or you have bit flips due to cosmic rays then don't expect anything of course).

Message is successfully sent when `ch <- x` returns. Otherwise, if it panics, it's not really being sent and if you don't recover than you could claim it's lost (however, it would be lost due to application logic). Panic can happen if channel is closed or, say, you're out of memory.

Similarly if sender is putting into the channel in non-blocking mode (by using select), you should have a sufficient buffer in your channel, because messages can be "lost" (although somehow intentionally). For example [`signal.Notify`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#Notify) is working this way:

> Package signal will not block sending to c: the caller must ensure that c has sufficient buffer space to keep up with the expected signal rate.

Answer (score 0):

Message can not be lost. It can be not sent.Order of goroutines execution not defined. So your endless for loop can receive from only one worker all time, and even can sleep if it isn't in main thread. To be sure your queue works in regular fashion you better explicitly in 'main' receive messages for each worker.